# Bringing a div back from .hide or .fadeOut onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so this is the example HTML.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">
 <div id="link">
  This is a link
 </div>
</a>

<div class="example">
 Example div 1
</div>

<div class="example">
 Example div 2
</div>

<div class="example">
 Example div 3
</div>
```

Whenever #link is clicked, all the divs with the class .example are hidden.

```
$("#link").click(function ( event ) {
  $(".example").hide();
});
```

or

```
$("#link").click(function ( event ) {
  $(".example").fadeOut("fast");
});
```

Now whenever any spot on the page is clicked, all of the .example divs return.

Is it possible? It doesn't all necessarily have to be done with jQuery.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').live('click', function() {
    $(".example").show();
});
```

Comment: Perfect. How can I make this only available after the .example divs have been hidden?